# Registration of dynamic websocket at application initialization time and at runtime has different endpoints exposed

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-websocket, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to register websocket dynamically.For instance, i have registered '/sampleEndpoint' at runtime so ServerWebSocketContainer will register it and start publishing data on that endpoint. But now if i do the same process during application initialization time in PostConstruct than i am unable to connect to '/sampleEndpoint' but have to append '/websocket' at the end so url become '/sampleEndpoint/websocket' when connecting from client side. Why we are getting different endpoints at different situations?

I have attached github url to the code.

https://github.com/pinkeshsagar-harptec/code-sample.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's how that SockJS option works: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket-fallback.

If you client is not SockJS, then you have to add that `/websocket` sub-path.

Not sure though why it doesn't work for dynamically registered endpoints...

In the case of `@PostConstruct` it is not dynamic: we still do the stuff within configuration phase of the application context, so it is able to add our endpoint into a static `HandlerMapping`. The dynamic nature is applied a bit later, when all the `@PostConstruct` have done their logic. You don't need to start that flow registration manually though since the auto-startup phase has not passed yet withing `@PostConstruct` handling.

Re. `IntegrationDynamicWebSocketHandlerMapping`: it sounds more like a bug and I need to investigate more. I guess you still use there that SockJS option and it has to be applied for dynamic endpoint as well.

Thank you for your patience! I'll investigate and fix it ASAP.

**UPDATE**

The fix is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3581.

Comment: OK. I found the problem. The static `WebSocketHandlerMapping` is evaluated against its registration when respective bean is created. With the dynamic registration with kinda don't have a hook yet to properly evaluate a registration at runtime...

Comment: Can I have any workarounds so that I don't have to wait for milestone 5.5.1 release?

Comment: Well, don't use SockJS on that dynamic endpoint! Technically you don't need it at all because you found that you have to use that extra `/websocket` sub-path in case of `@PostConstrcut`. The endpoints registered later on just don't support SockJS yet. Only that my fix can do that trick.